# Отправке письма на почту smtplib

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

При запуске данного кода получаю ошибку socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Ипользую данную ОС Linux aaa-tobefilledbyoem 5.15.32-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 28 09:16:36 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux

В настройках аккаунта гугл Ненадежные приложения, у которых есть доступ к аккаунту - доступ небезопасных приложений разрешен

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("email@gmail.com", "password")
server.sendmail("email@gmail.com", "email@gmail.com", "test")
```

Comment: Судя по сообщению об ошибке, на первый взгляд она может быть связана не с самим кодом, а с неправильным именем сервера или проблемами с DNS. Поэтому лучше уточнить, проверили ли вы доступность SMTP-сервера (попробуйте просто сделать ping smtp.gmail.com и убедитесь, что именно тот адрес исползуется в коде, что нет опечаток).

Comment: спс помогло, в /etc/resolv.conf добавить nameserver 8.8.8.8 перезапустить sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service